# Ubuntu user access restrictions

Tags: ubuntu, administrator, restrictions, access-control

I want to create an user account for each users at our office, where 2 users can have the full permission, whereas other users have limited access, say /var/www/html/ or /home/username.

Answer (score 0):

Might I humbly suggest that you find a Unix/Linux system administrator to help you, as I think the scope of security issues and configuration is orders of magnitude more complex then your post suggests.

One of the simplest ways to do this is to create accounts for everyone, and then provide the 2 administrators with the root password and let them use su.

A more appropriate way to handle the matter would be to add these users to the "adm" account

This answer only scratches the surface of the problem space though.

```
groupadd -a -G adm username
```

and then edit /etc/sudoers by using visudo and add a line

```
%adm ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Then the admin users can do sudo COMMAND to execute the command as root, or sudo /bin/bash to get a root shell.